# Euler angles of joints in a kinematic chain with constraints

Tags: python, opengl, rotational-matrices, kinematics, inverse-kinematics

I want to find the euler angles that allow the transformation from the image on th e left-hand side to the image on the right-hand side (see below). Joints `A` and `B` have a set of contraints:

- Local coordinate system XYZ given by the angles `[0, 0, 20]` (other joints may have different coordinate systems). I think this is always relative to the origin (I am reading from an .amc and .asf files)
- A direction `D` and a length `L`;
- Some joints only allow transformation in one or two axes;
- The points `A` and `B` are part of a kinematic chain.

[image]

**QUESTION:**

- How to compute the rotation matrix that allow the transformation from **`A`** to **`A'`** taking into consideration their local coordinate system and the rotation constraints?

**Please Note** I am not looking for an inverse kinematics algorithm, in the sense that I already have the joint angles between two segments. I am having trouble to understand how to deal with **rotation restrictions**, a **local coordinate system** and **direction**.

Comment: The amc file already contains the joint angles. What more do you need?

Comment: @jcampos it is unclear what you want to achieve. My guess is compute the change to get from pose A to pose B but If I get it right I see no point for doing that as you got the Euler angles for both poses so just interpolate between them (to obtain animation). Or am I missing something ?  Adding a sample input/output would probably clear things out